# How to set values along y-axis using kichart

Tags: android

I am developing the graph using kichart. But i don't know how to set the values along the y-axis like x-axis values and more thing how to remove the trial version tag in the image. I am getting the value as "0.00" along the y-axis. How to modify values like x-axis. is kichart is better to implement the line graphs? if No, then please suggest me the other way.

```
code
```

public class chartview extends Activity

{

```
LineView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    String xaxis[]=new String[4];

    xaxis[0]="2006";
    xaxis[1]="2007";
    xaxis[2]="2008";
    xaxis[3]="2009";
    float line1[]=new float[4];
    line1[0]=120;
    line1[1]=240;
    line1[2]=500;
    line1[3]=100;
    float line2[]=new float[4];
    line2[0]=100;
    line2[1]=650;
    line2[2]=700;
    line2[3]=300;
    float line3[]=new float[4];
    line3[0]=50;
    line3[1]=50;
    line3[2]=50;
    line3[3]=50;
    Aitem items[]=new Aitem[3];
    items[0]= new Aitem(Color.BLUE,"pauOut",line1);
    items[1]= new Aitem(Color.GREEN,"pauOut",line2);
    items[2]= new Aitem(Color.YELLOW,"pauOut",line3);
    lv=new LineView(this);
    lv.setTitle("Yearly Budget");
    lv.setAxisValueX(xaxis);        
    lv.setItems(items);
    setContentView(lv);
}
```

}

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i don't know how to set the values along the y-axis :

```
lv = new LineView(this);
lv.setYAxisRegionStart(50f);
lv.setYAxisRegionEnd(500f);
```

> more thing how to remove the trial version tag in the image.

that's easy, [buy](http://www.kidroid.com/purchase/) it.

Comment: among achartengine and kichart which one is better for developing the graphs?

Comment: achartengine, because it is open source.

Comment: Please can u send the demo achartengine for line,bar and piechart

Comment: please send all links regarding the achartengine for line, bar and chart

Comment: Here are the [demos](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-0.7.0-demo-source.zip&can=2&q=) I think it contains most of what you requested.